# How to make None or empty dict Field in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

How create the pydantic Model that will accept `{} or None`?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Wheel(BaseModel):
    diameter: int


class Car(BaseModel):
    wheel: Wheel | None = None


@app.post("/test")
async def test(car: Car):
    print(f"{car=}")
```

Need to be valid:

1. `{"car": {"wheel": {"diameter": 10}}` - works fine (no error)
2. `{"car": {"wheel": null}` - works fine (no error)
3. `{"car": {"wheel": {"foo": "bar"}}` - works fine (raise error)
4. `{"car": {"wheel": {}}` - not working (raise error)

Expected behavior for case 4:

- return 200 without errors
- wheel object is None

```py
car.wheel # None
```

PS:
It would be great if an empty dictionary `{}` could be replaced with `None`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Wheel(BaseModel):
    diameter: int | None = None


class Car(BaseModel):
    wheel: Wheel | None = None

    @validator("wheel")
    def verify_wheel(cls, v):
        if v.diameter == None:
            return None
        return v


@web_app.post("/test")
async def test(car: Car):
    print(f"{car=}")
```

Comment: It realy works but I prefer dont touch Wheel class (not set Optional for field)
And `@validator` is depricated so need to use `@field_validator` and set `mode="before"` in arguments

Answer (score 0):

Use optional and union from typing

```py
from typing import Dict, Optional, Union
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
  
app = FastAPI()
  
  
class Wheel(BaseModel):
    diameter: int
  
  
class Car(BaseModel):
    wheel: Optional[Union[Wheel, Dict]]
  
  
@app.post("/test")
async def test(car: Car):
    print(f"{car=}")
```

Comment: This will return code 200 on request body: `{"wheel": {"foo": "bar"}}` but must return error